# okhttp post request not successful

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i am working on push notification for android . everything was working fine but suddenly the gcm id(gcm token) is being returned as null.. should i re register the project and obtain a new project id as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931926/issue-in-getting-token-id-in-android).. or am i going wrong somewhere. please educate me
i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345292/gcm-reg-id-is-empty)
 below is the sample code

```
  @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.google_app_id);

      try {
        token = instanceID.getToken(senderId,GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,null);
        Log.d("register_Token: ", token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences, false).apply();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly where a blank registration ID is being returned, but its not important to realize that  [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) registration is an asynchronous event and does not happen right away. So calling `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);` right after will not give you the registration ID only a blank string.

In order to properly get the registration ID after your device has registered with the GCM servers you need to handle the following callback in your  [GCMBaseIntentService](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client):

`protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)`

That is where you will get the registration ID and where you should register with your application server.

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered,
registrationId));
ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
}
```